# What to do if OP is confused about basic things like creating a folder?

Tags: discussion

I am facing a really ugly situation answering a question. If you will go through the discussion you will notice, he is really confused and too much worried that he can not apply his common sense.

How do I handle such a situation?

*[Where do I put jQuery code in WordPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35910786)*

Comment: Pass them on to user3929948 - s/he has, aparrently, lots of time to answer such questions.

Comment: @MartinJames and who is that man ?